# ".htaccess" file not working at all

Tags: .htaccess

I have this code in my htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC]
```

This help to remove the .php extension in my url. but now I've been trying for weeks to rename a URL I have.

`article.php?num=5` to `article/num/5` or maybe the title of the article it self nothing has worked so far. this is what I tried using.

```
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9].+)/?$   article?num=$1  [NC]
```

Yet I always get internal server error i really need help with this its been frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

Your RewritePattern doesnt accept the **/num/** segment, you need to adjust it so it matches your your uri **/article/num/digits** . Change your pattern's regex to this

```
^article/num/([0-9]+)$
```

Comment: just tried your fix now am getting error 404 not found

Comment: i tried tweaking it to this again  `RewriteRule ^article/num/([0-9].+)$   article.php?num=$1` it works but without any styling just blank html with texts

Comment: @dapo to fix your css and other relative resources,  add a base tag in head section of your webpage **<base href="/">**

Answer (score 1):

Try it like below rule,

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/num/([\d]+)$ $1.php?num=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: when i entered url like this `article/num/5` it changes it to `article/num/blog` what can i do

Comment: How come? do you have some other rules working and please clear your cache too before trying.

Comment: i like your fix but it still give me the same issue after clearing cache. please review it and see whats wrong